# Reset the skewing values in a fabric object

Tags: html5-canvas, fabricjs

I have a fabric ellipse object  which is scaled and skewed. I want to recreate the same ellipse with no scaling and skewing. I assume this could be achieved by calculating new values for `rx`,`ry` and `angle` by offseting the scaling and skewing values. I managed to offset the scaling values, but I am not able to figure out the calculations to offset the skew values.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Jsfiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/jwp2yysh/

Please see the sample code. I want the blue ellipse to alligned inline with the red ellipse.

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');

var redEllipse = new fabric.Ellipse({
  rx: 80,
  ry: 50,
  originX: 'center',
  originY: 'center',
  fill: '',
  stroke: 'red',
  strokeWidth: 1,
  top: 180,
  left: 240,
  angle: 30,
  scaleX: 1.23,
  scaleY: 1.4,
  skewX: 25,
  skewY: 0
});

canvas.add(redEllipse);

var blueEllipse = new fabric.Ellipse({
  rx: redEllipse.rx * redEllipse.scaleX,
  ry: redEllipse.ry * redEllipse.scaleY,
  originX: 'center',
  originY: 'center',
  fill: '',
  stroke: 'blue',
  strokeWidth: 1,
  top: redEllipse.top,
  left: redEllipse.left,
  angle: redEllipse.angle * redEllipse.scaleY / redEllipse.scaleX,
  scaleX: 1,
  scaleY: 1,
  skewX: 0,
  skewY: 0
});

canvas.add(blueEllipse);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.20/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="c" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```

Comment: Why you are not using skewX/skewY in blueEllipse?

Comment: I want the blueEllipse to have no scaling/skewing but it should appear similar to redEllipse

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are looking for something like this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jw58ny65/).

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');

var redEllipse = new fabric.Ellipse({
  rx: 80,
  ry: 50,
  originX: 'center',
  originY: 'center',
  fill: '',
  stroke: 'red',
  strokeWidth: 1,
  top: 180,
  left: 240,
  angle: 30,
  scaleX: 1.23,
  scaleY: 1.4,
  skewX: 0,
  skewY: 0
});

canvas.add(redEllipse);

var blueEllipse = new fabric.Ellipse({
  rx: redEllipse.rx * redEllipse.scaleX - 10,
  ry: redEllipse.ry * redEllipse.scaleY - 10,
  // rx:80*1.23,
  //ry:50*1.4,
  originX: 'center',
  originY: 'center',
  fill: '',
  stroke: 'blue',
  strokeWidth: 1,
  top: redEllipse.top,
  left: redEllipse.left,
  angle: redEllipse.angle,
  //angle:30,
  scaleX: 1,
  scaleY: 1,
  skewX: 0,
  skewY: 0
});

canvas.add(blueEllipse);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.21/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="c" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```

From what I could understand, your calculation of `rx` and `ry` is correct. The problem with calculating the `angle` using the formula you have mentioned in the code is probably not taking into account the skew-ness of the original ellipse.

A simpler way would be to replicate the angle `redEllipse.angle` to make the new ellipse inline.

To make it inside the original one, you just need to reduce the `rx` and `ry` values by some common factor (I have used `10`).

Comment: Thanks for the answer but this is not correct because my redEllipse has a skewX of 25 whereas the redEllipse in your sample code does not have any skewX.In fact my question was how to account this skew values in blueEllipse properties